# MySQL Select last month data by current_timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

till today when i was working with MySQL and needed to perform actions with date/time i was using int column with unix timestamp and there was no problems, but today after reading some guides i decided to test timestamp column with "current_timestamp" by default.

So i am interested how to select last month data by column where info is in "2012-09-07 00:23:30" format? And maybe there some tricky queries what will give me data from the start of this month (not last 30 days, but from 09-01 00:00:00 till today) ?

Comment: I faced a similar problem not long ago and ended up calculating the dates through server side language (in this case php but any will allow you to do this). Anyway, also interested in this :)

Comment: @jribeiro Posted an answer, have a look.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will give you the last month:

```
WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW();
```

This from the start of the month:

```
WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND NOW();
```

The BETWEEN is nothing special, it's just a shortcut for

```
dateColumn <= ... AND dateColumn >= ....
```

Hmm, I guess the NOW() comparison is not actually needed, since all the records will be before now.

So just do:

```
WHERE dateColumn >= STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Dynamic start of current month:

```
WHERE dateColumn >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE())-1 DAY
```

All this does is extract the day of the month from the current date, then subtract that many days less one from it.

Comment: The problem I see with this is if the query needs to be dynamic. I do this but I still have to find the start of the month on server side. But maybe this goes beyond what the OP requested. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [common_schema](http://code.google.com/p/common-schema/), it's easy to install and has lots of great tools, including a function called [`start_of_month()`](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/start_of_month.html) that is exactly what you are looking for:

```
select * 
from your_table
where your_column >= common_schema.start_of_month(now())
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a mysql timestamp, something like `2013-09-29 22:27:10` you can do this

```
 select * from table WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)))=9;
```

Convert to unix, then use the unix time functions to extract the month, in this case 9 for september.

Comment: better yet `select * from table where MONTH(time) = (MONTH(NOW()));`

Comment: What about this month next year?

Comment: maybe select * from table where MONTH(time) = (MONTH(NOW())) and YEAR(time) = YEAR(NOW()));