# How to select data from a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I have a MySQL table that has data that is dated with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I am trying to query the data from the last 30 days using PHP and then convert it to a JSON object before sending it back to my UI. Currently I am only getting an empty JSON object back. This is my current ajax code.

```
function dailyReport(){
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200){
        document.querySelector("#reportsOutput").innerHTML="";
        document.querySelector("#reportsOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","php/dailyReport.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

And this is my current PHP code

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port)or die(mysql_error());


$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE timestamp=current_timestamp";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$rows=array();

while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[]=$r;
}

$response=json_encode($rows);
echo($response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the SQL query may be the problem here.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE timestamp=current_timestamp";
```

is saying, "Select all the items whose timestamp is right now." However, I think you mean to do something along these lines, where you select a date that is greater than the current timestamp - 30 days:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(current_timestamp,INTERVAL 30 DAY)";
```

I recommend using something like [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) to test your queries before you put them in your PHP, it makes it easier to hunt bugs like this down.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer - you need to modify your query.

[MySQL Select last month data by current_timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309289/mysql-select-last-month-data-by-current-timestamp)